# Where can I download Windows driver for Magic Mouse?

Tags: windows, drivers, bluetooth, magic-mouse

[Uneasysilence.com](http://uneasysilence.com/archive/2009/11/14588/) seems to have removed the driver from their site. Does anyone know here I can get the driver now?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the XMouse drivers found here: http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Comment: Left and right clicks work, but not the scrolling and swiping gestures. Any way to make them work as well?

Comment: It's my understanding that you have to map everything on the mouse yourself using "X-Mouse Button Control - Setup". 
http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmbc.png

Comment: I tried to configure the "Wheel Up" and "Wheel Down", but they didn't seem to help.